# How can I optimize damage for a ranged ranger from level 1 to 6?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization, striker

I'm going to start playing with my friends again and they will start a campaign in D&D 4e.
The campaign begins at level 1 and I decided that the team needed a ranged striker.
the last time I played was with D&D 3.5 so I don't know as much about the new system.

The group is formed by good optimized characters (although not the best for roleplaying reasons) and is formed by:

- Dwarf mage
- Dragonborn paladin
- human avenger
- half-orc warrior
- human barbarian
- human ardent
- human psion
- elf shaman
- human cleric

They have most of the books and my question is:
What **feats,powers,ability scores, equipment** are the best to **optimize damage** for the first 6 levels for an ranged ranger?

Past that I think I would catch them in reading the books.

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Sidenote: Unless you actually _want_ to reduce the number of players, [split the group in two.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124/how-do-i-run-a-game-for-a-larger-group/30039#30039)

Answer (score 6):

All of your answers can be found in the [ranger's handbook](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2533216). In short, focus on twin-strike spam.

[Shoot-to-thrill](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2883061) is a level by level build of a ranged ranger by lordduskblade which focuses on making twin strike everything it can be.

Pick up a greatbow ,bow expertise, weapon focus, and bracers of archery to complete this supremely boring build.

Comment: Right, twin-strike is mathematically the right choice almost every single turn, but I shoot two dudes or this dude twice is supremely uneventful.

Comment: I find that it helps to describe each time you use a power with some detail.  Think about the Avengers movie or the Lord of the Rings trilogy- you could describe what Hawkeye and Legolas do as "Twin Strike.  Twin Strike.  Move.  Twin Strike."  Or you could describe it as shooting standing on one foot, or your quiver as rotating arrows for you.  When you're adjacent to the enemy, they may get an OA, but frame it as sticking the arrow through them with your hand before you pull it back out and shoot it through them.

Comment: @JLan all builds can be narratively interesting if you put the effort into it. Some classes/builds support this, and some put the entire onus on the player to do so. This would be one where the onus is completely on the player