# How do I play with 8 people?

Tags: dnd-5e, group-scaling

So, this is my second D&D campaign as a dungeon master and I wanted to try it with more than 3 people. I told 5 other people that they could join in and we will start in a month.

However, I’ve read that over 5 people will create complications. Should I try it with 8 people, if so then how?

If not, I’ll just do 5. I know this is more of a personal problem question, but in the name of D&D I need some help please.

Comment: I'd suggest looking through questions [with the group-scaling tag](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-scaling), a lot of those are for how to adjust for larger (or smaller) parties.

Comment: No worries, group organisation and management are on topic. Welcome to the site! Have a [tour].

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124/23750, and references therein.

Comment: If the linked question doesn't provide you with what your'e looking for, please let us know what's missing and we can help you update your question accordingly to get it reopened.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: I'll note that the linked question is for 4E, and this question is for 5E. Many of the answers there apply, but at least one is 4E-specific.